# How to subset a phyloseq object to perform ancombc in R?

Tags: r, phyloseq

I am trying to follow ANCOMBC tutorial at https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ANCOMBC/inst/doc/ANCOMBC.html

However I got stacked in the beginning, since I was not able to subset the atlas file.

The code is the following:

```
data(atlas1006)
tse = atlas1006[, atlas1006$time == 0]
```

And it generates the following Error message:

```
> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument
> 'j' in selecting a method for function '[': $ operator not defined for
> this S4 class
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"$ operator not defined for this S4 class" may be because your data is saved as an S4 object instead of an S3 object (see [here](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/r-objects-and-classes) for more details about these object types in R). You can easily test this by using the function:

`isS4(atlas1006)` where a `TRUE` output means that it is an S4 object.

You can use the `str(atlas1006)` or `View(altas1006)` functions to examine the structure of your data object in more depth. Without being able to see the data, I would at this point recommend trying to access your data by using the `@` operator to call a specific slot in your S4 object, which would be roughly equivalent to using `atlas1006@time` instead of `atlas1006$time`. If you provide the output you get from using the `str(atlas1006)` function, I may be able to give you more specific advice.